# Product idea/approach : Folder based disk organization

Tags: projects-and-solutions, product

Sweet..I bought myself a 1TB portable harddrives this week. Don't you just love how much data you could store on one of these disks? The fact that I could store my bluray rips on to my portable harddisk and that my lg lcd tv can do HD rips right from the drive - that's amazing practicality right there! However, life it seems, is never so simple. I have 100s of movies unorganized in one huge folder, which is exactly what I needed to annoy myself while browsing the same on my tv to play a single movie. That got me thinking...

**What if I had an automated way to organize movies into folders such that my folder-browsing-on-a-lcd-tv-or-a-comp would make my life a little easy?**

I started thinking about this... I browsed a little in this context and I realized that if only I could **"tag my movies somehow and create folders on-the-fly based on tags using hardlinks"**, I would have addressed my problem. I googled a bit to find software that works in the above fashion, only to find none.

A few more days of serious thought (as you know by now.. I think a lot.. and I guess this question is starting to sound like a blog rant/post of sorts...), in the interest of humanity, I thought I should come up with a generic way to address this:  **What if someone wanted to organize photos... organize music.. organize software?!**

Turned my grey cells off for a while and here is an approach I came up with to solving my what-if scenario.

- Tag / Group tag individual files (rely on a slick GUI to do it fast and do it good) - Adobe Flex/Eclipse RCP to do this?
- Create hardlinks to each of the tagged files.

The first point is self-explanatory. The second (coz I am talking windows here), refers to making use of mklink.exe.

Consider a scenario where I have 2 movie files: I have a movie file "Transformers.avi" tagged as "english, action, bluray, sci-fi, imdb-top-50, must-watch-with-kids" and another movie file "The Specialist.avi" tagged as "english, bluray, thriller, adult". Here are a few of the possible locations I want to see my Transformers to be found:

- [root directory]->all-tags->english
- [root directory]->all-tags->bluray
- [root directory]->all-tags->english->all-tags->bluray
- [root directory]->all-tags->bluray->all-tags->action
- [root direcotry]->all-tags->english->all-tags->action->bluray->all-tags->imdb-top-50

Given that windows has a limit of 1024 hardlinks to a single file, I probably would be allowed 7 unique tags per file. Each sub-folder will have an "all-tags" folder. Having it named "all-tags" makes it more accessible when order by name.

I believe this approach when automated to let you configure tags you want and where the hardlinks are created for you, helps you organize stuff effectively.

I don't know if there are better things out there. I would like your inputs on this approach and other possible ideas. I would like to gather inputs here and release something to sourceforge for everyone to use in a couple of weeks. I am sure, I can count on your positive response as always.

Comment: This really does sound like a problem that is more suited to a database rather than a file-system oriented solution.

Comment: I beg to differ. If you are going to have a database that stores tags, you would need special software that reads this meta data and displays and lets you browse categories. I can pretty tell you that there is nothing open source out there which solves this problem. You have stuff like, Windows Home Media Server and the likes which do decent with organization. Doing it with folders is rather simple and effective.

Comment: Having said that, it is pretty much a real question,something that has been on my mind for 2 weeks now and I wanted the community inputs before I proceed with it. It feels weird that you have voted it for close, when it is not subjective/argumentative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe hardlinks are not a good approach. Reason? A standalone player won't play them, and I wouldn't like a program who's made for tagging to tell me to stop making so many tags because of a Windows limitation on hardlinks (remembering each tag will increment the number of links exponentially).

Plus, "help" is not a good tag.

And I've had an idea once that I'm still planning to make some day to sort my own files - put the files in a big storage each below a GUID foldername (filename untouched) and store metadata in a sqlite database to be used by a smart file browser.

Comment: @Camilo This is something that I tested with my LG LCD TV. Any player that can do NTFS file formats, I presume would, recognize hardlinks. Yes, may be you wouldn't like a program that would tell you the limitations of windows file systems, however, having something that automates your file organization when you stick to some rules is better than manually doing it or not doing it at all.

Comment: You presume, but I've saw many players that barely handles FAT long names, I wouldn't try putting a hard link there, who knows what the firmware supports. You could try.

Comment: @Camilo Your idea sounds interesting, only that you would need a specialized piece of software (a smart file browser) that would run on multiple platforms and would never run on custom firmware of an LCD TV/ Bluray Player/ AV Receiver that can read your harddisk. Sticking to the basics of filesystem and working around its limitations is probably a little more realistic approach?

Comment: @Camilo Forget players for a while, and tell me what is wrong with organizing an external harddisk such that your content on it is more accessible say when you access the same on a laptop? Secondly, hardlinks are IMHO not bad - you delete your "main" file, all your hardlinks are deleted automatically - You update your file/change  your file name, your hardlinks are still good. All these do not happen with softlinks.

Comment: Well, there is another problem - tagging every file takes a long time. Plus... lemme think. for 4 levels of folders and 4 tags you have 256 (4 * 4 * 4 * 4) hardlinks to one file.

Comment: The reason I wouldn't use something like this, supposing the hardlinks tagging would work, is really the initial investment in time I'd need. Remember, people who'd use file organizing software are by definition lazy enough not to organize their files well. Maybe if you generate these tags automagically from some data... well, for MP3s you have ID3, for movies I guess each media container has it's own metadata format (but I guess MediaInfo's DLL would help). Nothing against hardlinks versus softlinks, really.

Comment: @Camilo like I pointed out, I would need a faster way to do tagging, I would probably rely on a slick GUI way to doing it. Probably multi select files, have a mouse gesture way to tagging - in short, I intend to make tagging easier with state-of-the-art UI controls. I guess, mathematically, the limit would be 6 tags per file i.e 6P6 = 720 hardlinks.

Comment: No, 6 tags and 6 levels of folders would be 6*6*6*6*6*6= 46656 hardlinks

Comment: @Camilo - Nice point there. But given the fact that I would want this as a generic product to organize stuff into folders, I really can't rely on metadeta provided by mp3s/media containers? I like the idea though.. for instance, I guess I could connect to IMDB to retrieve tags for movies.

Comment: @Camilo It is an arrangement of folders - means it is a permutation?

Comment: Well, *I'd use* a non-multi-platform software as long as it helps me with the files on my PC where I need it most.

Comment: Oh, yeah, it'll be 6*5*4*3*2... sorry * facepalm *. By the way, if IMDB doesn't have an API, I'd leech the info off the HTML pages. I've done something like this before and it works sweet.

Comment: @Camilo as you can see, I am trying to solve an everyday problem of my life. I am sure there are a lot of people who face very similar issues (lots of movies are up for download these days - legally/illegally, majority of lcdtvs have usbports and support media playing, lot of people use windows machines:)?) May be something I can come up with, could help a buch of people out there for free - that's just my intention in this effort.

Comment: @Camilo yep, IMDB doesn't have an API. I could gather info from HTML pages, but this would work for movies mostly - won't go well with music / software / photos organization. (works for my case, but in a generic scenario it wouldn't)

Comment: Yes, IMDB would work only for movies. But, software has metadata (applications sorted by vendor, fonts sorted by designer, etc) and photos too (even geo tags sometimes). Music generally is rich in metadata.

Comment: @Camilo Sure, sounds like a good idea. Thank you for your inputs.

Comment: You're welcome. I really recommend you to use MediaInfo for metadata on multimedia containers, it has an incredible support.

Answer (score 1):

I was considering doing something similar to this with music for detecting duplicate songs and auto-organize funcationality.

For your application, I wouldn't recommend using any shell programs through Java.  Exception handling becomes difficult, and your application becomes bound by the shell interface and implementation (i.e. windows versions or installations affect your application behavior).

I would use a database with a few tables: Files, Tags, and an association table.

The Files table would list the physical location of each file, the filename, and a unique identifier.  This way, you can maintain information about each file without having to modify it for every tag association.

The Tags table would list each tag, and any metadata you want to store for each tag.

A third table, maybe 'FileTags' would store the assocation between tags and files.  When adding tags to the stack, you would add a statement to the WHERE clause, and the list of files with all of the tags would be returned.  This structure would also allow open your codebase up to other designs, such as include/exclude (autocomplete with X buttons), or possibly search.

If implemented in Java, your app would be platform independent, and would allow a very large number of tags and files.  You can then use the system default application for opening the media file, and the user can make the selection in their native OS.

Comment: appreciate your answer. However, I would like to add that the need for organization in my scenario stems from the fact I need to browse my ntfs harddisk on a LCD TV. This can only be achieved when content is organized well into different folders - making it a case for using hardlinks.

Answer (score -1):

Reiser4?

...

(I mean nevermind Hans, but the tech...)

[disclaimer: Not a hacker. I know nothing of programming/coding, never mind filesystems & databases. I can barely code decent HTML even, if at all. Hey y'all! :D]

[footnote: does plain HTML5 work here? Too lazy to close my tags hehe :p]